# Select field with zfcuser and custom module

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I've started last week learning ZF2. I've succesfully installed the skeleton application and the ZfcUser module. 
I decided to edit the registration form as suggested in the ZfcUser Wiki:
https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/wiki/How-to-modify-the-form-objects-used-by-ZfcUser

and add a select field, The same you can find in the official form Docs.

But the select is not displayed correctly as it's rendered like an input field. You can see 
[here](http://ilvelista.fraz.org/user/register) an example.

Here my Application/Module.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Zend Framework (http://framework.zend.com/)
 *
 * @link      http://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication for the canonical source repository
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2005-2012 Zend Technologies USA Inc. (http://www.zend.com)
 * @license   http://framework.zend.com/license/new-bsd New BSD License
 */

namespace Application;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\Form\Form;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('translator');
        $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
        $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

        $events = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $events->attach('ZfcUser\Form\Register','init', function($e) {
            $form = $e->getTarget();
            $form->add(array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
                    'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'Which is your mother tongue?',
                            'value_options' => array(
                                    '0' => 'French',
                                    '1' => 'English',
                                    '2' => 'Japanese',
                                    '3' => 'Chinese',
                            ),
                    ),
                    'name' => 'language'
            ));         
        });
        $events->attach('ZfcUser\Form\RegisterFilter','init', function($e) {
            $filter = $e->getTarget();
            // Do what you please with the filter instance ($filter)

        });
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Please, can anyone help me understanding this behaviour and point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code is fine, the issue is with the standard view provided by the user module for rendering the form.

register.phtml

```
<dd><?php echo $this->formInput($element) . $this->formElementErrors($element) ?></dd>
```

This is using the input view helepr to render any extra element. This should probably be the formElement helper which is a generic helper to render any element depending on it's type:

```
<dd><?php echo $this->formElement($element) . $this->formElementErrors($element) ?></dd>
```

that will work a charm, but It would probably be best to add in an extra check such as:

```
<?php elseif ($element instanceof Zend\Form\Element\Select): ?>
        <dd><?php echo $this->formSelect($element) . $this->formElementErrors($element) ?></dd>
<?php else: ?>
```